# Devise Registrations Controller "fields cant be blank" on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, devise

I am trying to create a devise user via a post request to my rails api. When i submit the request, I get the following message back :

```html
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<form class="new_user" id="new_user" action="/users" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="aD/tTW9DM0nXQap07ZAH6U5Uu/YP2hUA+ThM28VGKKjuZJuJw6c2JbYK6m4T737d7ue9S4RIlP1s7Y4xcMgy/g==" />
    <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2>
            2 errors prohibited this user from being saved:
        </h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Email can&#39;t be blank</li>
            <li>Password can&#39;t be blank</li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <div class="field">
        <div class="field_with_errors"><label for="user_email">Email</label></div><br />
        <div class="field_with_errors">
            <input autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="email" type="email" value="" name="user[email]" id="user_email" /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <div class="field_with_errors"><label for="user_password">Password</label></div>
            <em>(6 characters minimum)</em>
            <br />
            <div class="field_with_errors">
                <input autocomplete="new-password" type="password" name="user[password]" id="user_password" /></div>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label for="user_password_confirmation">Password confirmation</label><br />
                <input autocomplete="new-password" type="password" name="user[password_confirmation]" id="user_password_confirmation" />
  </div>

                <div class="actions">
                    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign up" data-disable-with="Sign up" />
  </div>
</form>
<a href="/users/sign_in">Log in</a><br />
```

here is the data I am sending in my request, which I am making via Postman: http://localhost:3001/users/?email=testacct@yahoo.com&password=testpass

I have also tried sending the request with uppercase Email and Password fields

server logs:

```
app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:23:in `create'
Started POST "/users/?email=testacct@yahoo.com&password=[FILTERED]" for ::1 at 2019-07-16 17:13:55 -0400
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"email"=>"testacct@yahoo.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:16
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", ""], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:16
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:16
  Rendering /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/devise-4.6.2/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/devise-4.6.2/app/views/devise/shared/_error_messages.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/devise-4.6.2/app/views/devise/shared/_links.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/devise-4.6.2/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb (7.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 34ms (Views: 9.2ms | ActiveRecord: 5.5ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding:

respond_to :json

to the application controller
and removing all extra devise params sanitizers i had added. Additionally i added devise-token-auth gem and used that to set up my user routes

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to help you dissect your logs below.

TL;DR - You either need to remove the uniqueness validation in your User model (might be baked into Devise gem in general) which I wouldn't recommend **OR** just try it with a different email address and let me know how that goes. You can make them up for testing, it doesn't matter. Only formatting matters. Something@something.something should be fine.

**1. The Controller begins processing your request**

`Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as */*`

**2. Your parameters are getting sent, here they are**

`Parameters: {"email"=>"testacct@yahoo.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}`

**3. The database begins saving your user object**

`(0.2ms)  BEGIN`

**4. Line 16 in the registrations controller is probably where it checks validations**

`app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:16`

**5. The validations have been checked and this user (their email) already exists**

**5a. This is almost certainly because of a uniqueness validation in your user model**

`User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", ""], ["LIMIT", 1]]`

**6. Oh well, there can't be two users with the same email so the record is not saved (rollback)**

`app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:16 (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not resolve the issue. I can type in any email and get the same result. My initial thought is that the params are being passed in blank, hence   "WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", ""], ["LIMIT", 1]]"

Comment: Is it possible that there are front-end validations in your view?  The error it is giving you (the html) is very strangely formatted like it's an error in your views.  Is it possible to attempt creating a user without using Postman at all through a form in your app?  If you used scaffolds at all it would be _form.html in app/views/users

Comment: That's another thing that stood out to me. It's API only, yet i'm getting a html view instead of a json response. I know devise generates some views but i can't find where this is coming from

Comment: Devise is a little tricky because so much of it is abstracted but I'm willing to bet your issue is Devise being set to use the views it provides.  I believe the one in your error is here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb Definitely give it a try using their views and see if the postman input might be the issue.

Comment: I believe this was the primary issue here, as the response sent back was a full html page. As i noted earlier today, adding a respond_to json in my application controller and generating api-specific routes and views with devise-token-auth fixed this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Devise requires both a password, and a password confirmation entered as input, thus their field for password confirmation in your provided HTML. Try also sending the password again to `password_confirmation` in your POST request. It should look something like this: 
http://localhost:3001/users/email=testacct@yahoo.com&password=testpass&password_confirmation=testpass

Comment: Adding the password confirmation makes no difference in the error, still getting the same output and response